# How to compensate for missing features in some samples in Logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit a logistic regression function for data with some rows that have missing features values. (E.g Row one contain information for 7 features, and in row two feature number 6 doesn't contain any value) I am not allowed to delete any information. and not allowed to fill the missing values with any technique. How can I train the model to deal with such a case? So the equation will know to compensate for such cases.
Also, different scenarios, if I already have the logistic equation and I want to use it on some test set with missing features values, is that possible?

Comment: Please add some context to the question. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website.

Comment: added more information.